# Read two strings and int from .txt into struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to read the suit, rank, and card value (ex: heart seven 7" from a text file and input this to a struct. The code below outlines what I am trying to do, only I am not implementing it correctly. My question is; how can I fix my loop in order to increment through my text file, and assign suit to: deck[0].suit, deck[0].rank, and deck[0].cvalue up to deck[51]. I was able to loop correctly and assign the values to an array, but now I am stuck. I cannot also get the two c-style strings and the int value to copy to arrays correctly either. thanks for your help!

```
// deck of cards
// below are initializations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
//globals
const int maxCards = 52;

//Structs
struct card {
    char suit;
    char rank;
    int cvalue;
    char location;
};

struct player {
    char name;
    int total;
    char hand[3];
};

int main()
{

    //seed the time
    srand(time(NULL));

    //constants

    bool gameOn =true;
    int choice;
    char tempSuit;
    char tempRank;
    int tempValue;

    struct card deck[51];
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    ifstream myfile ("cardFile.txt"); //read cards from .txt

    if(!myfile.good())
    {
        cout << "Your .txt data file did not load         correctly" << endl;
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        myfile >> tempRank;
        myfile >> tempSuit;
        while(myfile.good())
        {
            int index=0;
            int length=0;
            int cvhold;
            int i = 0;
            while (tempRank[length] != '\0')
            {            
                length++;
            }
            deck[i].rank = tempRank[length];
            length ++;
            while(tempSuit[index] !='\0')
            {
                tempRank[length] = tempSuit[index];
                length++;
                index++;
            }
            deck[i].suit = tempRank[length];
            length++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, care about indentation.  Also, your `struct card deck` is one card short.

Comment: @matt If you have an array of size 51, `arr[51]` is not a valid index for that array.

Comment: ah i see, ill fix that. im fairly new to all this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your template for the *text-file* you used in the example:

```
 heart seven 7
 spade six 6
 ..etc
```

then your `struct card` with elements `char suit;` `char rank;` cannot certainly hold the values of the string "heart", "seven" etc.

As for reading the values. You already know the quantity (52=`maxCards`) you can just use a for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxCards; ++i)                                                                                                                                        
{
    myfile >> deck[i].suit;
    myfile >> deck[i].rank;
    myfile >> deck[i].cvalue;
}
```

where, I assumed that you have modified the `struct card` as:

```
struct card
{
     std::string suit;
     std::string rank;
     int cvalue;
     char location;
};
```

Comment: I cannot use strings, i have to use chars. so i changed them to char suit[8] and char rank [6]..That for loop is all i need to read in the values to the struct?

Comment: Hold on. Why can't you use strings?

Comment: You can package the read into an `operator>>(std::istream&, card&)`.

Comment: @Wug its for an assignment in class, we have to use c-style char arrays

Comment: i dont think that for loop works, it gives jibberish when i print out the deck